# handle mutiple duplicate error mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have User Schema like this

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },

  phoneNumber: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
});
```

When I post a user with duplicate `name`, `phonenumber` or `email`. I receive the error like this:
This is error message `E11000 duplicate key error collection: project.users index: username_1 dup key: { : "john" }`

So my question is that how I can know it is a duplicate name or duplicate phonenumber. I want to receive the error like this.

```
This phone number has been already used
This name has been already used
```

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the error in your error handler. You can get the path name and value using regex. Simple example:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.code === 11000 || err.code === 11001) {
        const pathRegex = err.message.match(/\.\$([a-z]+)/)
        const path = pathRegex ? pathRegex[1] : '';
        const keyRegex = err.message.match(/key:\s+{\s+:\s\"(.*)(?=\")/)
        const key = keyRegex ? keyRegex[1] : '';
        return res.status(409)
            .json({ status: false, message: `${path} '${key}' already exists`})
    }
}
```

You can also check [mongoose-unique-validator](https://github.com/blakehaswell/mongoose-unique-validator) that produces a mongoose 'ValidationError' that you can parse more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can use a `path` [validation mechanism](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/validation.html).

```
UserSchema.path('username').validate(function(value, done) {
    this.model('User').count({ username: value }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } 
        done(!count);
    });
}, 'User Name already exists');

UserSchema.path('email').validate(function(value, done) {
    this.model('User').count({ email: value }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } 
        done(!count);
    });
}, 'Email already exists');
UserSchema.path('phoneNumber').validate(function(value, done) {
    this.model('User').count({ phoneNumber: value }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } 
        done(!count);
    });
}, 'Phone already exists');
```

Comment: So your suggestion is performing 3 queries before trying to persist the document?

Comment: @RenatoGama The model has three unique keys, so if the task is to find if the doc is unique or not in three different keys, hence had three path validators mentioned, with `unique` errors, which is the actual ask. Please let me know if there is any alternative?

Comment: I am looking for an alternative as well!